# Using GCM to receive messages sent when device is not connected to internet

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use GCM to try and send messages to my application even when the device is not connected to the internet. I know that GCM usually waits till the device has internet and then sends it the message. However, when I test it with my app by disabling WiFi, sending a push message and then enabling WiFi I do not see a message being received. I am following the exact example from [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) site. Since I am using an `IntentService` and `BroadcastReceiver` I figured it would handle the case. Do I have to make any other changes to make it work while the device has no internet? Since

Comment: Was the message just delayed, or did it never arrive? It can take up to 15 minutes to the message to arrive when device reconnects to the internet. See answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016150/gcm-msg-delivery-times-are-wildly-erratic).